# Treating tuples and strings uniformly in python

Tags: python, string, tuples

This is an esthetic question about python. At its base it's about different behaviour of tuples and strings, as when I want to add a single entry:

String:

```
new_string = char + old_string
```

Tuple:

```
new_tuple = tuple([entry]) + old_tuple
```

I could replace `char` by `str(char)` but not by `str([char])` nor `tuple([entry])` by `tuple(entry)`.

This becomes a problem when I want to treat tuples and strings uniformly, which seems like a good idea since abstractly they are essentially the same thing (just not the implementation as seen above).

Concretely, suppose I want to enumerate all words of length `n` over with entries coming from a word `letters`. A very descriptive way is this:

String:

```
def words(n, letters):
    if n == 0:
        return [ '' ]
    else:
        return [ c + x for x in words(n - 1, letters) for c in letters ]
```

Tuple:

```
def words(n, letters):
    if n == 0:
        return [ tuple() ]
    else:
        return [ tuple([c]) + x for x in words(n - 1, letters) for c in letters ]
```

The best way I came up with to treat both cases uniformly is:

```
def words(n, letters):
    word_type = type(letters)
    if n == 0:
        return [ word_type() ]
    else:
        return [ letters[i:i+1] + x for x in words(n - 1, letters) for i in xrange(len(letters)) ]
```

which is less decriptive.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: *which seems like a good idea since abstractly they are essentially the same thing* - I disagree - Strings and Tuples are very different, and I don't see the use case for treating them the same way - why do you want to do this? It appears you take in strings and tuples of letters - the best answer is probably to unify them to a single type before this point.

Comment: I agree with @Latty. Can you describe the use-case you have that requires you to perform this operation on both tuples and strings?

Comment: So what's the abstract difference between a string and a tuple of characters? (Note: the answer shouldn't involve the sentence "Python does not have a character type".) As a matter of fact, there are programming languages where strings are precisely tuples of characters. The use case is: I have students do something like the above. In most languages there is an obvious type for "words" but in Python there are two, so I want my sample code to work with both.